# How exactly does chemotherapy cause anemia?

Tags: cancer, pharmacology

I’ve been trying to figure this out for the past few hours but I still can’t find something as in depth as I’m looking for. So far all I’ve found is that chemo drugs kill bone marrow cells and some other drugs can damage the kidney which decreases red blood cell production, but I’m looking for something a bit more in depth.
From my understanding, there are multiple “groups” of chemo drugs (such as alkylating agents, antimetabolites, etc), so I assume there isn’t one answer which covers every group (unless, hopefully, I am wrong). I’ve read explicitly that some groups, like alkylating agents, are known to cause death in bone marrow cells. This also made me question if anemia/bone marrow cell death is a side effect from every chemo drug. If not, is it known which groups of chemo drugs are most likely to cause anemia and how exactly they do cause anemia (as in anything more in depth than “they kill red bone marrow cells”)? I’ve also read that some chemo drugs containing platinum can damage the kidney, but I wasn’t able to find how exactly it damages the kidney in a way that red blood cell production is decreased. I’m assuming this is due to a decrease in EPO production/secretion? If anyone has any relevant information/sources I would greatly appreciate it! Sorry if this is really specific and if this happens to be the wrong place to post such a question.

Comment: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemotherapy